# Synchronize two folders on the same Mac os X Lion

Tags: macos, sync, time-capsule

Is there a way to synchronize two folders on Mac OS X Lion on the following scenario please:

1) Each time I update or delete a file on a given folder, the other folder will change accordingly.

2) This should work *both ways.*

3) If I should run a program, it should run hide upon start up.

**Can anyone point out a free solution please ?**

Thanks a lot.

If you are curious about why do I need this?
Well, apparently we CAN'T point Google Drive to a Time Capsule folder.
So I thought that, perhaps we can place Google Drive on my `local machine folder` and use some sort of *service* to synchronize my `local machine folder` with my `Time Capsule folder`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use the Automator.

Here is a step by step guide to sync folders.

http://www.bananica.com/Geek-Stuff/Synchronize-two-folders-on-a-Mac-with-Automator-and-Rsync/